# When can a total/linear-order be extended to a well-order

Tags: order-theory

The axiom of choice tells us every set can be well-ordered and an easy exercise is that every partial-order can be extended to a linear-order and a linear-order on a set is a well-order iff any of the following (equivalent) conditions hold:

1. Transfinite induction works for the entire ordered set.
2. Every strictly decreasing sequence of elements of the set must terminate 
   after only finitely many steps (assuming the axiom of dependent choice).
3. Every subordering is isomorphic to an initial segment.

But when (and how) can a linear order be extended to a well-order, I'm guessing that one of the conditions must be a bottom element, any other conditions?

Thanks in advance, any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean, when can a ***partial*** order be extended to a well-order? The question doesn't make sense for a linear order.

Comment: A linear order can't be extended to a linear order different from itself. Therefore, a linear order can  be extended to a well-order if and only if it's already a well-order. A partial order can be extended to a well-order if and only if it satisfies your second condition, i.e., it has no strictly decreasing infinite sequence of elements; equivalently, every nonempty subset has a minimal element. Of course the axiom of choice is assumed.

Comment: Maybe he means conditions in which we can embed the order in a well order